# passing data from Tableview to CollectionView SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make pass a data where whenever I click on users, it will be shown on a collectionView. However, I do not know why whichever tableview row i click, it adds my top user, followed by second and etc. How should I go about this? (both my collectionView and tableView are on same view)

i used protocol to send data from tableview to collectionView

```
protocol toRefresh {
func updateCollectionView()  }
```

and I declared a variable to store the selected Users:

```
var chosenUser: [User] = []
```

as for my tableView

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let user = users[indexPath.row]
    chosenUser.append(user)
    updateCollectionView()
    }
}
```

In my collectionView

```
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return chosenUser.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
    self.chosenUser.remove(at: indexPath.item) // here crashes as well
}


func updateCollectionView() {
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To delete an item from the collection it must be deleted from data source first

```
self.chosenUser.remove(at: indexPath.row)  
self.collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
```

To retrieve

```
let selected = users.index(of:chosenUser[indexPath.row])
```

Comment: How about retrieving? Because as of now,doesn't matter whichever rows I click,it shows the user from the most top cell,followed by second and so on

Comment: Thanks! the remove at, worked! but i couldnt append user on my click..I edited the screenshot of what i meant, i clicked on tester 2 to be added on top, but tester 1 will be added and shown first and so on